# WooCommerce remove_action and add_action

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have in my WordPress project `woocommerce-functions.php` in here I have all my woocommerce edits.
So, I'm trying to make two different single-product pages.
I have in the `woocommerce-functions` file function called "diff_prod"

```
// Check if the product have specific Category
function diff_prod() {
    global $post;

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

    if( is_array( $categories ) ) {
        if( in_array( 'diff-prod', $categories ) ) {

            $diffe = 'im different!';

        } else {

            $diffe = 'im not!';
        }
    }

    return $diffe;

}
```

and then I'm trying to make if statement:

```
if(diff_prod() == 'im different!'):
    /* Remove "Add to Cart" -Button from Single Product Page */
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
endif;
```

But for some reason this not working.
I have read the code up to bottom couple hundred times and everything make sense, but clearly I'm missing something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, Is it a single product ? Where do you want to place you code ?

Comment: @Benoti yes, I'm trying edit the single product page. What do you mean where I want to place the code?

Comment: Did you try to put the code in your woocommerce file in an action (ie: init) ?

Comment: Nope, I have just tried to place the code in my own `woocommerce-functions.php` file. Also, I tried to place the if statement directly in the `content-single-product.php` where it actually works but then the product tabs disappeared for some reason, even that I used exactly the same hooks than the default one.

Comment: When I wrote woocommerce file, I talk about your woocommerce-functions.php ;-) woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart is a function where you can try to add your statement. In wc-template-functions.php. Just copy paste it to your woocommerce-functions.php and modify it with the statement.

Comment: @Benoti Awesome, I got it work. Thank you for your advise. It was clever idea, helped a lot :).

Comment: So I make an answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own dedicated function and overwrite a default one when a function is in a `function_exists` statement.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' ) ) {}
```

You can use the `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` function from `wc-template-functions.php`

Just copy/paste this function to your woocommerce-functions.php and modify it with the statement you want.

This method is simple if you don't want to add multiple template based on specific conditions.